# Layered storage: automatically move from SSD to HDD Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, storage

I have a 120GB SSD and a 2TB HDD

Is there a way to "merge" this, so I just store my programs and data to the respective folders, and let the system move the less frequently used stuff from SSD to HDD.

I don't want to be bothered with deciding to put stuff on SSD or HDD.

I have a laptop, so it must be a software solution; nothing like HighPoint RocketHybrid 1220

I have seen [Making SSD & HDD work together like a hybrid](https://superuser.com/questions/293932/making-ssd-hdd-work-together-like-a-hybrid) but that question is 6 years old.

Comment: You can mount the HDD as a folder. Which would make it seem as one drive to you as end user.  But automatically moving files? (and not just any file, e.g. OS files should not move), .... I doubt it.  You could use only the HDD as main drive though and use the SSD for caching. Neither is precisly what you asked so not posting it as an answer.

Comment: Can you explain why this isn't a duplicate of the question you linked? The fact it's 6 years old isn't sufficient.  If you feel that question needs updated answers, the proper course of action is to post a [Bounty](https://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it stating that as the bounty reason.

Answer (score 1):

Youmight want to look into the `ReadyBoost` feature, it works similar (while not as brilliantly) to Linux's `bcache` mechanism by using the SSD as a cache for the HDD.